Skype shortcut - voicecall by default
I have a Skype contact shortcut on the home screen of a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 5.0.2. When I click the shortcut, I get a dialogue box with a series of options i.e. voice call, message, or video call. Rather than this, I would like a voice call to be placed by default i.e. no dialogue box.
Is there a way to do this, or if not, some kind of workaround? I'm not averse to using another voice calling app, but it needs to do what I have outlined i.e. place a call when the shortcut is clicked.
One workaround I have considered is recording and replaying a string of events. However, before going down that route, I wish to rule out more straightforward solutions first.

Seems like your Galaxy Tab 10.1 is one of the version from 2011. Recent Skype version in Play Store requires Android 8. What Skye version do you use?

Thanks. Skype version is 8.15.0.440

There's a very old duplicate question in 2010 where an (now deleted) answer referred to an app from 2012.

Thanks. Seems that app no longer available. With regards recording and playing touches I came across a project on Github which looks interesting. Wonder if anyone has heard of this or anything similar?
